# What to do in lyx so that the compiled pdf will have "links" to the sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I am not sure how to explain my question that in the title, so I will provide a picture, below.
I want that the compiled pdf, when run on pdf readers will have the behaviour of Table of Contents, but my problems are:

1. Its just doesn't happen on my files, and even when I add ToC (And I want this behaviour even without ToC)
2. I was thinking that the problem may be because I used unnumbered sections, but it doesn't happen even with numbered sections

my settings are:

1. Working mainly with Lyx
2. doc class is Koma-scriptArticle
3. using mostly Unnoumbered Parts, Sections, etc.
   [image]

- EDIT: Im adding 2 minimal example files, english and hebrew. In both of them I dont get the required behaviour
  [here](https://ufile.io/kqbt50mp)
- FINAL EDIT: So far, I have discovered those things:

1. It's recommended to have LyX take care of it by going to Document > Settings > PDF Properties and checking the box "Use Hyperref Support" (credit is for @scottkosty)
2. It is working even for hebrew! For that you need to remove the 'culmus' package (Im not sure how is hebrew working for me without this package, maybe it is because I downloaded some CTM fonts)
3. To achieve this behaviour even for unnumbered parts, sections, etc one can 'get'  this result by adjusting the 'Numbering&Toc' in 'Document Settings' (The meaning is that you use *numbered* sections, but the number won't appear)

Comment: You need the hyperref package for such bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that and will update

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hey again! I have included 'usepackage{hyperref}' to my Lyx preamble.
Do I need to do something else to make it work? I really hope that there is a solution where Parts, Sections, etc are automatically being referenced.

Do you mind to write your answer in a comment, so I could vote up for you?

Comment: And if its possible, I would like to have this effect also on theoerms & claims

Comment: by default theorems are not in the bookmarks. It would be probably possible to do it, but you would have to provide a complete, minimal example for standard latex that can be used for tests and find out yourself how to convert it into a lyx answer.

Comment: Instead of adding the package loading to preamble, it's recommended to have LyX take care of it by going to Document > Settings > PDF Properties and checking the box "Use Hyperref Support". You can add additional custom options there.

Comment: @scottkosty Hey, I did that, But for some reason it does not help, and on the compiled pdf there is no sign of those references. what can i do?

Comment: btw, in Lyx itself, there is the possibility to navigate by sections, and aslo, as I added ToC, then in the ToC menu in Lyx I can see that the document is arranged by its sections.
But again, nothings of that is in the compiled PDF

Comment: Do you use `\chapter*` or `\addchap` for unnumbered chapters?

Comment: umm no. I dont use chapters at all. Just parts, sections, subsections,..

Comment: @e.ad I suggest you follow the page here to create a minimal example .lyx file and minimal example .tex file and paste them into your question: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty ok, thanks, I'll do it, and post here later today

Comment: @scottkosty I have done it

Comment: I had to remove culmus and remove your included math macros file. But the PDF has bookmarks for me. I get the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/no5e0g9qmj0ujrx/englishminimalexample.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Yes, I can see that. So perhaps this is issue with that culmus package?
(I added it for support in hebrew, but maybe I need to find another solution if I want that support in bookmarks)
Do you have any idea that I can try to preserve culmus and have the bookmarks?
Thank you for your help

Comment: @e.ad Unfortunately I have no idea. If you narrow it down to the culmus package being the problem, perhaps edit your post accordingly and try to make it as specific as possible (e.g., "culmus package prevents PDF bookmarks") and post as simple of an MWE as you can. Please read that link again (https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample). I hope you find a solution!

Comment: @scottkosty Ok, I will try do some research. maybe its simpler than I think. Thank you very much. Would you mind to write your comment as an answer? So I could upvote you and mark this thread as answered

Comment: @e.ad Done. No need to upvote since I don't think the answer is that useful :). But indeed it's nice to accept an answer so this leaves the "unanswered queue". Thanks for your attention on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing culmus and your included math macros file, the bookmarks show up for me. This suggests the problem might be coming from using culmus or from the included math macros file.